# Elastic query changed mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple elastic mapping:

```
my_mapping {
    properties: {
        name: {type: 'text', fields: {"type": "keyword", ignore_above: 256}},
        userName: {type: 'text', fields: {"type": "keyword", ignore_above: 256}},
    }
}
```

I have been able to successfully store data. Although i can query the data via a POST and:

```
{   
  _source": [ "userName", "documentName"],    
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query":       "johnsnow",
      "fields":      [ "userName", "documentName"]
    }
  }
}
```

I can see my original mapping from above now contains a query prop, is this the expected behaviour?

```
my_mapping {
        properties: {
            name: {type: 'text', fields: {"type": "keyword", ignore_above: 256}},
            userName: {type: 'text', fields: {"type": "keyword", ignore_above: 256}},
            query: {
                properties: blah blah
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that you didn't hit the `_search` endpoint but the `_mapping` one and your `query` DSL structure actually got indexed into your index and the mapping was modified as a result.

Comment: @Val this makes sense to me.

Comment: Just checked what endpoint i hit, i believe it was _search, for example: http://dev.elastic.psy.com:9100/area_dev/name_mappings/_search/?size=1000

Answer (score 0):

**As suggested by @Opster Elasticsearch Ninja, this may be a reason that you have not specified your own explicit mappings.**

**But, here in the following example, I have created a new index with no explicit mapping, thus not configured the field names and types**

Adding Working example with sample docs, search query and search result.

**Index Sample Data :**

```
{
    "name":"johnsnow",
    "username":"joh12"
}
```

**Search Query :**

```
{
  "_source": [
    "username",
    "name"
  ],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "johnsnow",
      "fields": [
        "username",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
 "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2876821,
            "_source": {
                "name": "johnsnow",
                "username": "joh12"
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Index Mapping :**

```
    {
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In the end, after posting data and running search query, the index mapping remains exactly same as that of after posting index data and no query properties is generated.**